# Unable to connect Camera from Wowza

Tags: wowza

We have configure live streaming in wowza from camera

when tried to Testplayers it says unable to connect

Is there any where we need to set the camera password in wowza ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

below command is to push the rtsp stream to WOwza server

> ffmpeg -re -i SampleVideo_720x480_20mb.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f rtsp
>   rtsp://[username]:[password]@[CLoud server IP]:[port]/live/myStream

you can check whether the video stream is coming or not by login to the Wowza server, and go to Applications->select your live application->Incoming Streams

you can view the Video stream using VlC player

> vlc rtsp://[cloud server IP]:[port]/live/myStream

[Have a look at below link how stream to Wowza engine using ffmpeg https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-live-stream-using-ffmpeg-with-wowza-streaming-engine [1](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-live-stream-using-ffmpeg-with-wowza-streaming-engine)